# input file on mouseup show hidden div, show file dialog box after hidden div closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can get an `input=file` to show an alert on mouseup and after closing the alert, have the dialog box open.

**What I want to do now is show a hidden div on mouseup and have the dialog box open *AFTER* it's closed. How can I achieve this?**

With alert box

```
$('#inputFile').mouseup(function(){
    alert('Show alert box');
    });
```

With div(dialog box shows before div is closed)

```
$('#inputFile').mouseup(function(){
    $('div').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to tackle this problem, but this is what I would suggest:

Change your input=file to a basic button (type=button). When this button is clicked, open your hidden div with a "close" button on it. This close button would call a function. Said function should open a file prompt dialog and close the div.

Comment: This is actually a pretty easy approach, but I'm wondering if there is something easier, like not allowing the dialog box to open until the div has been closed. Can that be manipulated? If the alert box can take precedence over the file dialog box, then maybe there is a way to make the hidden div more precedent over the file dialog box.